# Can't view the website on the LAN stored on XAMPP server

Tags: localhost, xampp

I'm trying to access website located on XAMPP server on my other computer located on the same LAN network. I am able to see welcome screen of XAMPP server, i.e., `192.168.0.22/xampp/` but when I am pointing to my website, i.e., `192.168.0.22/xampp/website/` it says:

> OBJECT NOT FOUND! The requested URL was not found on this server.
>   ERROR 404.

However I am able to view the website on localhost. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be `192.168.0.22/website/`?

Comment: Defo not. This is a problem with permission I guess. URL 192.168.0.22/xampp/website/ works perfectly fine on the localhost but when I try to open this on a different PC (same LAN) it gives me ERROR 404. Think it might be something related to httpd.conf and permission configuration.

Comment: Maybe a firewall restriction on the host?

Comment: I'm a silly bean. You were right 192.168.0.22/website/ works great. Have no idea why I came up with /xampp/ in the middle! Probably drilling too many hours in front of the screen.

Comment: Firewall settings were changed beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Michael (see above) `192.168.0.22/website/` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have following folders in the  document root i.e. `htdocs/xampp/website`; you need to store your files in this document root only then it will work.

Comment: Website is defo stored under ULR mentioned by you. As mentioned above to @Michael it works fine on the localhost but refused to be opened on clients within the same LAN.